# uniqueness of adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I'm trying to prove the uniqueness of the adjoint operator between two **finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces** $E$ and $F$. My idea is to simply use the isomorphism between finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces and the Euclidean spaces while also using the Euclidean inner product by its definition.

1. The origional problem:

   Suppose $(E,(\cdot \mid \cdot )_{E})$ and $(F,(\cdot \mid \cdot )_{F})$ are two finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. Verify that to each $A\in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ there is a unique $A^*\in\mathcal{L}(F,E)$ , such that $\forall x\in E, y\in F$, $(Ax\mid y)_F = (x\mid A^*y)_E$.

   Also there are following subquestion asking to prove the form of the $A^*$ is exactly $[\overline{a_j^k}]$, and so on.
2. My proof is like this:

   Suppose $\dim E=n, \dim F=m$, and let $[A]=[a_k^j]\in\mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ (the upper symbol is the *line* number), then $\forall x=\left( x^1, \cdots , x^n \right) \in E ,y=\left( y^1,\cdots ,y^m \right) \in F$,

   \begin{align}
   \left( x\mid A^*y \right) _E&=\left( Ax\mid y \right) _F=\left( \left( \sum_{j=1}^n{a_{j}^{1}x^j}, \cdots ,\sum_{j=1}^n{a_{j}^{m}x^j} \right) \mid \left( y^1,\cdots ,y^m \right) \right) _F
   \\
   &=\sum_{k=1}^m{\left( \sum_{j=1}^n{a_{j}^{k}x^j\overline{y^k}} \right)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{x^j\sum_{k=1}^m{a_{j}^{k}\overline{y^k}}}
   \\
   &=\sum_{j=1}^n{x^j\overline{\sum_{k=1}^m{\overline{a_{j}^{k}}y^k}}}
   \\
   &=\left( x\mid \left( \sum_{k=1}^m{\overline{a_{1}^{k}}y^k},\cdots ,\sum_{k=1}^m{\overline{a_{n}^{k}}y^k} \right) \right) 
   \end{align}

   , and therefore $\left[ A^* \right] =\left[ \overline{a_{j}^{k}} \right] \in \mathbb{K} ^{n\times m}$, which is unique.

However, I think it quite unrigorous to directly use the Euclidean inner product on two random Hilbert spaces. Can anyone examine this proof? Thanks!

---

Update:

Thanks to @[Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan)'s hint, now I finished the proof, writing the matrix in the standard form between the two orthonormal basis, while the rest are almost identical. **Are there any other details to notice? And are there other approaches to proving it?**

Comment: Once you've proven that a finite-dimensional Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis it's perfectly rigorous. Have you done that yet?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there exists $B^*$ such that it satisfies the adjoint property. Hence we have $\left<x,A^*y\right>_E =\left<x,B^*y\right>_E, \forall x,y \in E,F$. This means $\left<x,(A^*-B^*)y\right>_E=0$ $\forall x,y \in E,F$. In particular, for any fixed $y$, take $x = (A^*-B^*)y$. Then the inner product axioms would imply $A^*=B^*$.